# Right and left rotation of a tree in python

Tags: python, tree, rotation

I use the class:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.key = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None
```

and I have created this tree:

```
n_12 = Node(12)
n_15 = Node(15)
n_3 = Node(3)
n_7 = Node(7)
n_1 = Node(1)
n_2 = Node(2)
n_not1 = Node(-1)

n_12.right = n_15
n_12.left = n_3
n_3.right = n_7
n_3.left = n_1
n_1.right = n_2
n_1.left = n_not1

n_12.parent = None
n_15.parent = n_12
n_3.parent = n_12
n_7.parent = n_3
n_1.parent = n_3
n_2.parent = n_1
n_not1.parent = n_1
```

I tried this code:

```
def rightRotate(t): 
    if t == None or t.left == None:
        return None
    n = t
    l = t.left
    r = t.right
    lr = t.left.right
    ll = t.left.left
    t = t.left
    t.right = n
    if r != None:
        t.right.right = r
    if lr != None:
        t.right.left = lr
    if ll != None:
        t.left = ll
```

But it didn't work, using the root node `n_12` it deletes some nodes. Why it didn't work and I don't understand why I don't have all the nodes. If I call `rightRotate(n_1)`, I have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write *"I have an infinite loop"*, but your code has no loop, so that must be happening elsewhere in your code.

I see two issues:

#### 1) Assignment should be unconditional

```
if lr != None:
    t.right.left = lr
```

This assignment is *also* needed when `lr is None`. If not, `t.right.left` will stay equal to `l` which is `t` at that moment, and so you indeed are left with a loop in your tree.

#### 2) Double threading

Your tree is double threaded, i.e., it also has `parent` links. But these are not updated in your `rightRotate` function. So either do without `parent` links (which is preferable), or adapt your code so that also the `parent` links are updated according to the rotation.

## Other Remark:

The following piece of code could be simplified:

```
if r != None:
    t.right.right = r   # was already equal to r
if lr != None:
    t.right.left = lr   # see above. should not be behind a condition
if ll != None:
    t.left = ll         # was already equal to ll
```

So that can be reduced to just:

```
t.right.left = lr
```

or even:

```
n.left = lr
```

## Final Code

With above mentioned changes, your function could be:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.key = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.parent = None

def rightRotate(node):
    if node is None or node.left is None:
        return node
    parent = node.parent
    left = node.left
    left_right = left.right

    # change edge 1
    if parent: # find out if node is a left or right child of node
        if parent.left == node:
            parent.left = left
        else:
            parent.right = left
    left.parent = parent

    # change edge 2
    left.right = node
    node.parent = left

    # change edge 3
    node.left = left_right
    if left_right:
        left_right.parent = node

    return left  # the node that took the position of node

# your code to build the tree
n_12 = Node(12)
n_15 = Node(15)
n_3 = Node(3)
n_7 = Node(7)
n_1 = Node(1)
n_2 = Node(2)
n_not1 = Node(-1)

n_12.right = n_15
n_12.left = n_3
n_3.right = n_7
n_3.left = n_1
n_1.right = n_2
n_1.left = n_not1

n_12.parent = None
n_15.parent = n_12
n_3.parent = n_12
n_7.parent = n_3
n_1.parent = n_3
n_2.parent = n_1
n_not1.parent = n_1

# rotate the root
root = n_12
root = rightRotate(root) # returns the node that took the place of n_12
```

Just remove the lines with `parent` to get the single-threaded version.

Comment: Sorry, we start using Python 3 months ago so I don't know how to use it very well. We are used to have functions without taking self as argument, but we give simply the node that is the root of a tree (this means directly the tree because the root is connected to everything). This function works also if I pass as parameter my root node t as in my first code? What is the difference? How we use self (what I have to put at the place of self) if I want to call the function?

Comment: The problem is also that if I tried to use this code with the node n_1 it gives me the error for the last line of your code (telling that Nonetype object has no attribute parent. I put the condition that if left_right is different from None then the last line is executed. It works but then it delete the node -1

Comment: Since it has been two days I need some time to get back to this, but I will soon update. Please don't wait for two days to come back to me ;-)

Comment: There is the possibility to have the code without using self? But as a normal function not in the class. thank for the patience :)

Comment: I have updated my answer taking your comments into account.